# How the Simplex method can be applied in solving the following system of Linear equations

Tags: diophantine-equations

How the Simplex method can be applied in solving the following system of Linear equations?
\begin{align*}
x_1–x_3+4x_4 &=3 \\
2x_1–x_2&=3 \\
3x_1–2x_2–x_4&=1
\end{align*} 
Where
$$
x_1,\;x_2,\;x_3,\;x_4\geq0
$$
 What would be the proposed Objective function in this case?
 Further compare its solution to the solutions being obtained by other usual methods (Gaussian Elimination, Gauss-Jordan, etc…)

Answer (score 1):

You can make up any linear objective function you like, e.g. $x_1$.  The Simplex Method will find an optimal solution (which you  don't care about), but more importantly, it will be a feasible solution, i.e. it will satisfy the equations.

The "diophantine equations" tag seems misplaced, since you don't require an integer solution, at least if I understand the problem correctly.

Comment: i am agree about tag

Comment: will you please elaborate the second portion of question